# Alternate solution for @Conditional in Spring 3.1.1

Tags: java, spring, spring-java-config

I am stuck in a Spring 3.1.1 application without the ability to upgrade to 4.x so I can't use the @Conditional annotation to conditionally enable a Spring Bean. What is the easiest way to implement similar behavior in Spring 3.1.1? Currently I am not using Profiles and would prefer to implement something simpler. Any suggestions?

### EDIT...Further Clarification

I have a @Configuration file that contains all my JMS Configuration/Beans. I only want to load the beans in this file based on a true/false property in properties file. I need to be able to turn this functionality on or off based on a properties file. In Spring 4 the functionality was added to apply a @Conditional annotation and provide the condition to load a bean. I need to do the same thing, but in Spring 3.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating your bean if your property is set, else creating null?

```
@Bean
public YourBean yourBean(@Value("your.property.value") boolean enabled) {
    if (enabled) {
        return new YourBean();
    }
    return null;
}
```

That way it won't get used elsewhere.
If you need autowiring, you can autowire it then like:

```
@Autowired(required = false)
private YourBean someBean;
```

and check if it is present or not before use.

Comment: Your bean would have to return an instance of `Optional<YourBean>` instead of `null`, since if it returned `null`, that'd defeat the whole point.

Comment: @Makoto please explain? Spring automatically handles `Optional<YourBean>` type of dependencies so that they are only available if defined.

Comment: I'm not sure Spring 3.x would automatically handle that, given that `Optional` came in with Java 8, and Spring 3.x only supports Java 7...

Comment: Ah, that is true. Have to go with required = false then. Updated.